# OpenCV 3.2 Installed but unable to use it. load version 4.0 everytime

Tags: opencv, anaconda, opencv3.2

I have problem that it's struggling me. I use python (anaconda) for some codes. I'm currently doing the tutorials from openCV.

I create envs everytime I need to install new packages. These are the steps that I am doing:

create a new environment

```
conda install -c menpo opencv3=3.2.0
conda list
```

(make sure the version 3.2.0 is installed)

then I go to python to check the version:

```
python
import cv2
cv2.__version__
```

'4.0.0'

The problem is that everytime I tried to check if I'm using the 3.2 version. The 4.0.0 version shows up. btw the version 3.2.0 is installed since conda list shows it and it does not even shows the 4.0.0 version.

anyone has an idea why does this happens?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is suggested to create a conda environment and do the installation in tha activated environment. So there will not be conflict between packages. This worked fine for me.

Please try the below steps.

1) To create the conda environment:

```
   conda create -n <env_name> python=3.4 -y
```

Here env_name can be any name given for the conda environment.

Eg:

```
conda create -n opencv_test python=3.4 -y
```

2) Activate the environment:

```
   source activate <env_name>
```

Eg:

```
source activate opencv_test
```

3) Then you can proceed the opencv installation in this activated environment.

```
   conda install -c menpo opencv3
```

Then try importing. Hope this helps.